# mac os - virtualbox - oracle connection error - invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle, mac-os-x

I have followed the below step guide(URL) to setup Oracle on Mac OS. Everything is fine on the guest side. But, I am facing some issues in host level.

I can connect database in Guest (Virtual box) but, when I tried to open the connection from host then I got a below error message.

"ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

**Note:** I am unable to do the step to stop the firewall on Guest.

https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-install-oracle-database-on-mac-os-any-version/

http://blog.codiez.co.za/2013/09/setup-oracle-instant-client-ruby-oci8-gem-mac/

```
sqlplus hr/oracle@cdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Nov 18 13:32:48 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Update: file - /usr/local/oracle/admin/network/tnsnames.ora

```
cdb1=
 (description=
   (address_list=
     (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = 127.0.0.1)(port = 1521))
   )
 (connect_data =
   (service_name=cdb1)
 )
)
```

Comment: type usernames in capital - sqlplus HR/oracle@cdb1

Comment: No. It's not working. Actually the same is working on Guest (Virtualbox) os.

Comment: How You configure guest network? (NAT, bridge or etc) if NAT (default) - did You setup port forwarding? if Bridge - change tnsname and tnslistener from listen 127.0.0.1 to real guest address

Answer (score 1):

You can manual check password for HR (if You want - force SET it oracle)
Firewall is not important moment, because Oracle return You exactly error text

if all correct, it must be:

```
macbookva:instantclient_11_2 vladimir$ sqlplus HR/oracle@XE

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Nov 18 19:24:20 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

Comment: As I said above the username and password is working on Guest and not working in host only.

Comment: what information is in Your tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: Updated the information on my question.

Comment: ok, what about - sqlplus sys/oracle@cdb1 as sysdba ?

Comment: no.. it's not working

sqlplus sys/oracle@XE as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Nov 18 16:51:04 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name: ¸  ^[

Comment: I edit string - XE it is my database, Your will be - sqlplus sys/oracle@cdb1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31739/discussion-between-a-vlad-and-mr-black).

Comment: How You configure guest network? (NAT, bridge or etc) if NAT (default) - did You setup port forwarding? if Bridge - change tnsname and tnslistener from listen 127.0.0.1 to real guest address